# select value from xml when specific value match

Tags: xml, xslt

From the below XML, I am trying to fetch the value of clientID when hostName matches the passes argument using XSLT.

Suppose if the hostname is TSM-Client.toolslab.net then the clientID I should get like 4

```
<client_details>
  <message-body>
    <clientProperties>
      <e>
        <client>
          <clientEntity>
            <_type_>3</_type_>
            <clientGUID>D1247669-8818-45CF-943D-319090CA9F2C</clientGUID>
            <clientId>2</clientId>
            <clientName>commserve</clientName>
            <hostName>COMMSERVE.toolslab.net</hostName>
          </clientEntity>
          <cvdPort>8400</cvdPort>
          <evmgrcPort>8402</evmgrcPort>
        </client>
        <clientProps>
          <clusterType>0</clusterType>
        </clientProps>
      </e>
      <e>
        <client>
          <clientEntity>
            <_type_>3</_type_>
            <clientGUID>933007BA-EFCF-4CC2-838C-45B1E21F7200</clientGUID>
            <clientId>4</clientId>
            <clientName>tsm-client</clientName>
            <hostName>TSM-Client.toolslab.net</hostName>
          </clientEntity>
          <cvdPort>8400</cvdPort>
          <evmgrcPort>0</evmgrcPort>
        </client>
        <clientProps>
          <clusterType>0</clusterType>
        </clientProps>
      </e>
    </clientProperties>
  </message-body>
</client_details>
```

I am using below code but not getting the result, I am getting only blank

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="no" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//e">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string(./hostName)  = string($[client])">
          <xsl:value-of select="string(./clientId)" disable-output-escaping="no" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise />
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:param name="hostName"/>
<xsl:key name="client" match="clientEntity" use="hostName" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('client', $hostName)/clientId"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then call the transformation with a `hostName` param.

---

Note that this assumes there will be at most one matching client. Otherwise you would need to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('client', $hostName)">
        <xsl:value-of select="clientId"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Michael, thank you for your help but I am not able to put <xsl:param name="hostName"/> under Output tag. How to perform this?

Comment: Not sure what's stopping you.